# Android OpenGL - Help with C++ Conversion

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I'm trying to convert this C++ code to Android's Java. However, I'm using GL10 and glGetDoublev apparently isn't supported on OpenGL-ES. How else can I perform this function?

```
// Get point by reading z buffer and unprojecting to object coords
    void Pick(int x, int y)
    {
       GLint viewport[4];
       GLdouble mvmatrix[16], projmatrix[16];

       glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
       glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mvmatrix);
       glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix);

       int      winx = x;
       int      winy = winHeight - y;
       GLfloat  winz = 0.0;
       GLdouble objx = 0.0;
       GLdouble objy = 0.0;
       GLdouble objz = 0.0;

       // Get winz for given winx and winy
       glReadPixels(winx, winy, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winz);

       // Make sure there was something at the point
       if (winz >= 1.0)
       {
          qDebug("Nothing picked");
       }
       else
       {
          // Get object coords from win coords
          gluUnProject((GLdouble)winx, (GLdouble)winy, (GLdouble)winz,
                       mvmatrix, projmatrix, viewport,
                       &objx, &objy, &objz);

          qDebug("Pick: win=%d,%d,%.3f obj=%.3f,%.3f,%.3f",
                 winx, winy, winz, objx, objy, objz);

          // Place a marker at that position
          Marker marker;
          marker.point.x = objx;
          marker.point.y = objy;
          marker.point.z = objz;
          markerList << marker;

          // limit to two markers
          if (markerList.count() > 2)
             markerList.pop_front();

          Rebuild();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps glGetFloatv is supported?

Comment: @user786653 - Thank you, but its not :( Just integer and string.

Comment: Have you checked [this link](http://www.41post.com/1540/programming/android-opengl-get-the-modelview-matrix-on-15-cupcake)? Seems to be describing how get the relevant matrices.

Comment: @user786653 - I was able to get the matrices. However, since OpenGL-ES doesn't support reading the depth buffer with glReadPixels, I'm screwed.

Comment: I almost mentioned that the function would be unlikely to work even if you got the matrices, but I don't know enough about OGL ES :). Anyway, there are other methods of picking depending on what you need (Realtime Rendering (the book) mentions a few methods IIRC), or maybe you could get the depth buffer written to the color buffer somehow (pixel shader would be easy, if supported) and `glReadPixel` that? Good Luck.

Comment: glGetFloatv is supported in opengl es i've used it many times before! watch out though they do lead to a decrease in rendering performance by halting the OpenGL rendering pipeline

Comment: @user786653 - Thanks for your help, but you lost me on the color buffer. I'm not a big OpenGL guy, but I need it for this purpose. Could you elaborate or point me to some actual code examples of what you mean?

Comment: By the color buffer I just mean what's drawn on the screen so it's [like taking a screenshot](http://www.anddev.org/how_to_get_opengl_screenshot__useful_programing_hint-t829.html). So if you can get the depth buffer drawn into the color buffer you could read it that way instead (yes it will be slow).

Comment: Wow, I really don't understand how OpenGL works. I actually have implemented screenshot functionality already, but have no idea how to throw in all the depth values.

Comment: I'm mostly just throwing ideas out there as I haven't worked with OpenGL ES (only standard OGL). You should open a new question asking how to do 3D picking on android I bet other people have solved it.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem in my own Android OpenGL ES 1.0 forays. Since OpenGL ES 1.0 does not allow you to get the matrices directly (as far as I know glGetFloatv was not implemented in 1.0), as you wanted to do, you need to make a wrapper that tracks matrices.

If you use OpenGL ES 1.1, you can use glGetFloatv since it has been implemented.

Here is the website where I originally found the solution:
http://www.41post.com/1540/programming/android-opengl-get-the-modelview-matrix-on-15-cupcake

All implementation details are there.